# Stripboard: Linking Neighboring Rows

Tags: stripboard

If I need to link two neighboring rows for a stripboard build is there any reason I should make a wire link over just placing a blob of solder between them? This is for a guitar pedal so the board will be jostled occasionally but will be in an enclosure the whole time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from neatness, the ease of debugging, professionalism, beauty and a clear conscience, no.